# Relations as arrows and as objects - what are the arrows in the latter?

Tags: category-theory, relation-algebra

Since a relation $R$ from $X$ to $Y$ defined as a subset of $X \times Y$, the category of sets and relations is just that: the objects are sets and the arrows are the relations.

Is there a generally accepted definition of a category where (at least binary, 2-valued) relations are objects? If so, what are the morphisms between them?

Comment: Categories, like all mathematical objects, are tools. How you define a category depends on what use you want to put it to. What use do you want to put such a category to?

Comment: Yet many if not most mathematical structures are precisely defined, there's not a lot of options in defining what a group, ring, field, vector space, dynamical system, etc, are, correct? Why should it be different for relation - because of their diversity?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, here's one choice. $\text{Rel}$ can actually be made into a [2-category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-category) in the following way: if $R, S$ are two relations $X \to Y$, then there is a unique $2$-morphism $R \to S$ if and only if $R \subseteq S$ as subsets of $X \times Y$. If you think of relations as logical conditions, then this notion of morphism corresponds to entailment. This exhibits $\text{Rel}$ as a category [enriched](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_category) over [posets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). (Actually it is slightly better, namely it is enriched over [suplattices](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/suplattice) and in particular also enriched over [commutative monoids](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+monoid). This is closely related to the fact that $\text{Rel}$ has finite [biproducts](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/biproduct); see [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/) for details.)

Here's another choice. If $C$ is any category and you want to turn its arrows into objects of a category, you can take its arrow category $\text{Arr}(C)$. This is the category whose objects are the arrows of $C$ and whose morphisms are commutative squares. So you can also take $\text{Arr}(\text{Rel})$.

Again, the morphisms you end up using should be guided by what you want to do with them.

Comment: +1 for the options. It turns at least the category of endo-relations (ie, relations on a set $X$) has objects $(X,\rho)$ and arrows are relation-preserving maps, ie  $f:X \to Y$, is an arrow iff $x_1 \rho x_2 \implies f(x_1) \sigma f(x_2)$. (eg, this is exactly how Sossinsky defines the category of tolerance spaces) However, how to generalize to arbitrary relations or at least binary relations in $X \times Y$, given the answers you gave above?